# Equivalent of split_at_mut for HashMap?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following code (minimum example):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<usize, i128> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(1, -5);
    map.insert(2, 6);
    map.insert(3, 7);
    for i in map.keys() {
        if *i == 3 {
            continue;
        }
       *map.get_mut(&3).unwrap() += map[i];
    }
}
```

The borrow checker will complain that:

```
cannot borrow `map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

However, in this case I can be sure that the mutation I am doing is not interfering with the immutable references. For `Vec`, I would use `split_at_mut` here - is there an equivalent for that for `HashMap` in Rust?

**Edit:**

As a comment pointed out, let me be more specific about the problem I am trying to solve. I want to implement "merging" vertices in a graph into one vertex. For this I created a `HashMap`:

```
pub mergedVerticesList: HashMap<usize, HashSet<usize>>
```

which should map from a vertex to all the vertices that have been merged into that vertex. Since this can be done recursively, when undoing a merge between `u` and `merge_onto` I want to remove all vertices that have been merged into `merge_onto` because of `u` from `merge_onto`'s `HashSet`. Thus, the code looks like this:

```
for i in self.mergedVerticesList[v].iter() {
    self.mergedVerticesList.get_mut(&merge_onto).unwrap().remove(i);
}
```

Comment: What is really the problem you are trying to solve here? I have a feeling that this is an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and that there may be better ways to solve the actual problem instead of what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good point. I edited the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible as far as the `HashMap` is concerned. You could have cells as values to regain mutable access but I'd strongly advise against that. Can't you move the change out of the loop (it also saves from a repeated lookup per iteration). Something to the tune of

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<usize, i128> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(1, -5);
    map.insert(2, 6);
    map.insert(3, 7);
    let s = map.iter().filter_map(|(k, v)| if *k != 3 { Some(v) } else { None }).sum::<i128>();
    *map.get_mut(&3).unwrap() += s;
    println!("{:#?}", &map)
}
```